# Earlystopping in multiclassification model Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm facing a multiclassification problem, which for what I've built the following model:

```
def model_building():
  input = keras.Input(shape=(X_train[0]).shape)
  hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(20)(input)
  dropout1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(hidden1)
  hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(20)(dropout1)
  output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(hidden3)
  model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output, name='ClassModel')
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=[acc])
  return model
```

But when fitting, it shows me this error

```
from keras import callbacks
earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="loss", 
                                        mode ="min", patience = 5, 
                                        restore_best_weights = True)

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=40, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0,
                    shuffle=True, callbacks =[earlystopping])


# ERROR:
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 4 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 4
```

Is possible to build an `EarlyStopping` in a multiclassification problem? If possible, how?

Comment: That's nothing to do with the callback itself but a problem with your last layer. It should be something like `Dense(num_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)`

Comment: What did you change and what was the error? You need to use softmax.

Comment: @Frightera well, that was it. I've forgotten to add the num_classes, nothing to do with Earlystopping like you said